# Can "I am here to me" mean "I am here"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, difference

What is the meaning of

> I am here to me

Does it mean

> "I am here"

Why is the second sentence correct but the first one is not?

Comment: I think there is no such a phrase

Comment: Why are you trying to add "to me" to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I don’t think the phrase, *”I am here to me”* is going to make any sense as a sentence on its own. But English is extremely flexible, so if I’m allowed to add a comma, I can come up with one obscure example that might work.

Imagine two philosophers, Ms Arendt and Mr Descartes, are discussing how they know various things:

> **Arendt:** I mean, there’s nothing we can know for sure.
>
> **Descartes:** Really? Nothing at all? What about whether I exist?
>
> **Arendt:** No, not even that. For all I know, you are an illusion. You might not even be here!
>
> **Descartes:** Well, to you perhaps.
>
> **Arendt:** What do you mean, to me?
>
> **Descartes:** Well I might not be here, *to you*.
>
> **Arendt:** Right!
>
> **Descartes:** Ah, but what about *to me*? To me, Descartes? **I am here, *to me***.

As I said, obscure.

(Just to be clear: in this context, “to me” means, “from my point of view”.)